# Complex regex get closest

Tags: regex

I would like some help to finish my complex regex.

I spent some times on it and still can't figure out how I can achieve what I want

This is the text I want to parse :

```
Do [|83]([]?([]?([]?([]?([]?([]?([]?:))))):)([]?([]?:([]?:)):)([]?[]? :):)([]?([]?[]:):)([]?([]?[]:):) 
Bo [|18] pz ([]?:)\n la :\n[pl] 
Co [|76] pp ([]?:)
```

For readability, I put every text in one line only but please consider that they are not on a new line.

This is my regex so far :

`(\[\|(\d*)])+(?!\\\n).*([%\sa-zA-Z]*)(\((\[[^\[\]()?:]*])+\s*\?([^()]*):([^()]*)\))`

I'm reading every combinations of `[|NUMBER] ()` one by one. The process I apply on "()" depends of the  NUMBER related

When I'm parsing the first time, I'm getting this which is fine :

[image]

Then, I replace the whole value after my process :

Now, I do have :

```
Do [|83] blabla done Bo [|18] pz ([]?:)\n la :\n[pl]  Co [|76] pp ([]?:)
```

When I parse them once more, I got :

[image]

The number I got is not the good one. My question is : how can I get the closest one from the string I'm parsing after?

Thanks you for any tips

Comment: Not clear. What is an example output based on your input after all replacements?

Comment: For a more clear example (maybe) I would like to do a replacement based on the number preceding like :

`Do [|83] blabla 83 Bo [|18] blabla 18\n la :\n[pl] Co [|76] blabla76`

Comment: Can you give a simplified example? For example given this string, I want to match these groups? Like perhaps `(\[\|(\d+)])(?:[^:]*(\((\[])\?:\)))?` https://regex101.com/r/TZtK06/1

Comment: Yes!

For : https://regex101.com/r/EO2vaX/1 I want to only match : `[|18] pz ([]?:)` and not `[|83] blabla83
Bo [|18] pz ([]?:)`

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might shorten the pattern a bit and exclude matching both the square brackets and the parenthesis in the character class after matching the digit and `]`

```
\[\|\d+][^][()]*\([^()]*\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[\|\d+]` Match `[|` 1+ digits and `]`
- `[^][()]*` Match 0+ times any char other than `[` `]` `(` `)`
- `\([^()]*\)` Match `(`, than 0+ times any char other than `(` `)` then match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpNpm6/1)

Comment: Thanks for the demo! It worked well after some (very little) adaptations!